# Angular add div to deny background clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

What will be the best way to have a full-screen div between my content and my popup?

My issue is that I have my page but when the user logins for the first time I want to add a guide highlighting some components and showing an information window and that is done and working, however, the user still able to click on the links in the page and I don't want it to happen before he finishes the guide so I decided to add a full-screen div in the page.

After adding the div with the following CSS:

```
.backgroundDiv {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

It works but when my guide highlights some component that is out of view, it does:
`element.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'});`

But the scrolling is being applied to the background div instead of my main page and it is breaking the feature.

My popup HTML is something like:

```
<ng-container>
  <div *ngIf="display" class="backgroundDiv">
    <ng-container *ngIf="display">
     (...) // Popup HTML
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Edit: Is there a way to find out the actual size that my page has? Everything that I could find just gives me the user screen at max. If I could get the actual height I could use a dynamic height for my background div.

Comment: You should not waste time in doing this as Angular bootstrap modals are doing everything for us. It is widely used across the projects:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: @vipulpatel Well, modals won't allow me to scroll so it would give me the same issue and at the moment we have a custom component that we made to display the tour guide, that's why angular modals weren't an option

Comment: Make sense !!! Why dont you make your popup itself scroll-able.  Like fix popup eight is fixed to window (    max-height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);) and then inside popup, we see scroll. This is how bootstrap modal is implemented.     overflow-y: auto;

Comment: Well, the only way to achieve something similar to that and it was what I was thinking is finding how much height is my page, so then I could set my overlay to be that size (my edit there), otherwise, I can't achieve that since my popup will me moving each step and it's a small modal showing information about that component. for instance, filters, search fields, etc.

Comment: Yes your max height would be : max-height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem).  Explore calc function which would give. 100vh is 100 per vertical height and subtracting whatever you may desire

Comment: How about using bootstrap modal and overriding `.modal-open { overflow-y: auto; }` to enable scrolling?

Comment: @a_nain My issue with that is that the scrolling will be on the modal and not in my main body and my guide need to scroll into the body and not in the modal and that is giving me some issues when I get the current elements positions on the scrolling to reposition my overlay highlight and popup

Comment: Scrolling would be on <body>, which will have _model-open_ class. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/nain_1304/Lpgfx3ch/8/